# Regular expression validator not working

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am using two textboxes and a fckeditor and a button first textbox is for email address(To), second textbox is for subject.

on the button onclientclick iam validating the subject textbox and the fckeditor whether they are empty or not and if they are iam asking for confirmation

if iam not using this clientclick then regular expression is working fine but if iam using it is not validating at all it is just asking for confirmation and on clicking ok it is sending the email.

but i want to use both what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the "clientclick" validation to a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) (you can set that to have a client-side validation) and both will fire.